# Does mybatis change time zone while inserting into a DB?

Tags: java, oracle, mybatis, spring-mybatis, timestamp-with-timezone

While inserting a record into a table in Oracle, the time stamp in the created date column is 4 pm UTC(in the complete format eg...2020-05-20 10:30:20.15 UTC). That is verified even just before calling the save method of Mybatis. After the save method is called, the created date column in the new record in the DB does not have UTC as the time. It shows 4 pm Asia/Calcutta. The numeric part of the time stamp is correct but the timezone got changed.

Our code is in Spring framework -
mybatisMapper.save(events) .. the created_date column in events POJO is of java.util.Date type.
We are trying to insert a record in DB hosted in Montreal.
select dbtimezone from dual; 
DBtimezone of the sever - -04:00  means American/Montreal time zone(hosted in America/Montreal)

select sessiontimezone from dual;
session time zone - Asia/Calcutta.(because the application is running in India).

Data type of the created date column is TIME STAMP WITH TIMEZONE. 
Is mybatis changing the time zone by any chance or is it dropping it altogether and letting Oracle decide the timezone by itself?

Comment: On top of timezone I would check the `locale`. Can you check the one on your local system and the database host?

Comment: locale? Database locale? did not know about this. what are all possible causes of this? can you elaborate on how locale might cause the trouble here?

Comment: Not every country has a daylight saving time, if wrongly set could cause the issue.
I also second Basil Bourque and would get rid of java.util.Date

Comment: Even after trying OffsetDateTime, the problem persists. WHat could be the reason?

Comment: It should work. Just be sure to use the latest versions of the driver and MyBatis. In version < 3.5.0, MyBatis internally used `PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()` and that caused time zone related [issues](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/1081). Support of Java Time API varies between DBs/drivers. For `OffsetDateTime`, see [here](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/pull/1368#issuecomment-428922657) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

**Never use `java.util.Date`.** That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Among the problems with `Date` is that its `toString` method dynamically applies the JVM‘s current default time zone while generating its text. This creates the illusion of that zone being contained within the object while actually a `Date` (despite its misnomer) represents a moment in UTC. One of many reasons to avoid this class.

Since you did not post any code, I can only guess that your problem is that you are being misled by the lie told by `Date::toString`.

As of JDBC 4.2 we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database. Specifically, use `OffsetDateTime` class to exchange values stored in a column of a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` might also work depending on your JDBC driver, but oddly JDBC 4.2 does not require support for those two more commonly used classes. I generally suggest you store an `Instant` on your class, converting to/from `OffsetDateTime`.

FYI, the time zone `Asia/Calcutta` has been renamed `Asia/Kolkata`.

Example code

```
String input = "2020-05-20T10:30:20.15Z" ;
Instant instant = Instant.parse( input ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
```

Write to database.

```
…
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval from database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) ;
```

This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.